# React Native TextInput padding is not working while display is set

Tags: react-native, styles, padding, textinput

I have a textinput component that will appear after a button pressed.

```
const [inputDisplay,setinputDisplay]=useState("none")
<TextInput
    style={[CommonStyles.textInput, { display: inputDisplay}]}
    keyboardType="phone-pad"
    placeholder="Code"
/>

    textInput: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(155,155,155,0.9)',
        width: '100%',
        height: 40,
        padding: 8,
        borderRadius: 3,
    },
```

The padding is not working with display set. But when I delete the display setting, it works fine.

Any solution on this issue?

Comment: what is inputDisplay ?. in react-native you can only set Display to 'flex' or 'none'.

Comment: @sandeepsingh sorry that i didnt make it clear. It is a useState and it will change to "flex" when the button pressed.

Comment: i checked by putting 'flex' and it's working horizontally and to make padding work vertically you need to remove height or setMinHeight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try conditional rendering instead?

```
{display !== "none" && (
  <TextInput
    style={CommonStyles.textInput}
    keyboardType="phone-pad"
    placeholder="Code"
  />
)}
```

Then in your `CommonStyles.textInput`, you can add `display: 'flex'`.